# Dygraphs skip column

Tags: dygraphs

I'm working on a project with Dygraphs and here is my problem :

My data looks like this (loaded from a CSV file URL):

```
"TimeInt";"TimeStr";"A_DP_01012_H";
1471443131;"17/08/2016 14:12:11";0;0.314072;
```

Data is generated automatically from an external source.

So my problem is that I cannot remove TimeInt or TimeStr column, but right now if I use those data as is I get :

> dygraph-combined-dev.js:7015 Unable to parse '"17/08/2016 14:17:18"' as a number on line 59

So is there any way to skid first column of data and use second column as Xdata

Also, is there any problem using "TimeStr" or it really needs to be without it?

Thanks.